# Does running unit test need to run the Main method in the code to be tested?

Tags: c#, visual-studio, unit-testing

In C#, for unit testing only, do I need to write a Main method in the code to be tested?

I found that without Main method, rebuilding the code to be tested and the testing code will fail.

Is it correct that running unit test doesn't run Main method in the code to be tested? If yes, why does it fail to build without Main method?

Note that I am experimenting inside Visual Studio IDE, and the unit testing uses Visual Studio's unittest library. If without using Visual Studio IDE, will the rebuilding succeed?

Answer (score 2):

No, unit tests don't need `Main` to run and unless your test explicitly tests `Main` the `Main` method will not run during Unit tests.

Why your build fails - your main project is likely exe and not class library - so indeed it needs `Main`.

Fix - add `Main` or change project to "class library"